# How to clear all permissions from a file using NSIS?

Tags: permissions, installation, nsis

I'm building an installer, and I am trying to set a file to be executable only by administrators.

```
AccessControl::GrantOnFile \
"$INSTDIR/mercheckadmin.exe" "Administrators" "FullAccess"
Pop $0
```

I'm using that to grant permission, but I'm trying to figure out how to prevent regular users from opening the app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ClearOnFile` to give access to just one trustee but you might want to give full access to SYSTEM as well with `GrantOnFile "c:\path\thefile" (SY) FullAccess` after using `ClearOnFile`.

```
AccessControl::ClearOnFile "$INSTDIR\mercheckadmin.exe" "(BA)" "FullAccess"
Pop $0
```

The other alternative is to block access for specific trustees with `DenyOnFile`...